# Binding form elements to persistent storage in IntelliJ plugin

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I have just started trying to make my own IntelliJ plugin and can't figure out how to properly save persistent information on bound form components.

I followed the right click on form, Data Binding Wizard, and properly matched up everything that was listed. I then modified the generated methods to handle the objects (or in this case, one object) that could not be bound (a JSpinner).

**How am I supposed to get the persistent storage to automatically save/update when the state of a component on my form is changed?**

Here is my PersistentStateComponent class:

```
import com.intellij.openapi.components.PersistentStateComponent;
import com.intellij.openapi.components.State;
import com.intellij.openapi.components.Storage;
import com.intellij.openapi.components.StoragePathMacros;
import com.intellij.util.xmlb.XmlSerializerUtil;

@State(
        name = "Hastebin Configuration",
        reloadable = true,
        storages = {
                @Storage(id = "other", file = StoragePathMacros.APP_CONFIG + "/hastebin.xml")
        }
)
public class HastebinService implements PersistentStateComponent<HastebinService> {

    private String host = "hastebin.com";
    private String msgSuccess = "Share with Hastebin successful.<br>Link is waiting in your clipboard.";
    private String msgFailure = "Something went wrong.<br><br>Problem description: {error}<br><br>Please try again and it problem persists, contact the author.";
    private boolean logPastes = false;
    private int port = 80;
    private boolean useFileAssoc = true;
    private boolean useSSL = false;

    public String getHost() {
        return this.host;
    }

    public boolean getLogPastes() {
        return this.logPastes;
    }

    public String getMsgFailure() {
        return this.msgFailure;
    }

    public String getMsgSuccess() {
        return this.msgSuccess;
    }

    public int getPort() {
        return this.port;
    }

    @Override
    public HastebinService getState() {
        return this;
    }

    public boolean getUseFileAssoc() {
        return this.useFileAssoc;
    }

    public boolean getUseSSL() {
        return this.useSSL;
    }

    @Override
    public void loadState(HastebinService state) {
        XmlSerializerUtil.copyBean(state, this);
    }

    public void setHost(String host) {
        this.host = host;
        System.out.println("testing");
    }

    public void setLogPastes(boolean logPastes) {
        this.logPastes = logPastes;
    }

    public void setMsgFailure(String msgFailure) {
        this.msgFailure = msgFailure;
    }

    public void setMsgSuccess(String msgSuccess) {
        this.msgSuccess = msgSuccess;
    }

    public void setPort(int port) {
        this.port = port;
    }

    public void setUseFileAssoc(boolean useFileAssoc) {
        this.useFileAssoc = useFileAssoc;
    }

    public void setUseSSL(boolean useSSL) {
        this.useSSL = useSSL;
    }

}
```

Here is my form class:

```
import com.intellij.ui.components.JBScrollPane;

import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFormattedTextField;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JSpinner;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JViewport;
import javax.swing.SpinnerNumberModel;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class SettingsPanel {
    private JTabbedPane hasteTabConfig;
    private JCheckBox chkUseSsl;
    private JCheckBox chkFileAssoc;
    private JCheckBox chkLogHistory;
    private JTextField txtSuccess;
    private JTextField txtFailure;
    private JTextField txtDomain;
    private JLabel lblProtocol;
    private JSpinner spinPort;
    private JPanel rootPanel;
    private JScrollPane scrollPane;
    private JPanel scrollPanel;
    private JTable tblHistory;

    public SettingsPanel() {
        this.scrollPanel.setOpaque(false);

        this.chkUseSsl.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {
                updateProtocol();
            }
        });
    }

    private void createUIComponents() {
        // Scroll Pane
        this.scrollPane = new JBScrollPane();
        this.scrollPane.setBackground(new Color(230, 230, 230));
        this.scrollPane.setViewport(new CustomViewPort(this.scrollPanel));
        this.scrollPane.setOpaque(false);
        this.scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setBlockIncrement(20);
        this.scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setUnitIncrement(16);

        // Port Number
        this.spinPort = new JSpinner(new SpinnerNumberModel(80, 1, 65535, 1));
        JFormattedTextField textField = ((JSpinner.DefaultEditor)this.spinPort.getEditor()).getTextField();
        textField.setColumns(1);
    }

    public void getData(HastebinService data) {
        this.getUnboundData(data);
        data.setHost(this.txtDomain.getText());
        data.setUseSSL(this.chkUseSsl.isSelected());
        data.setUseFileAssoc(this.chkFileAssoc.isSelected());
        data.setLogPastes(this.chkLogHistory.isSelected());
        data.setMsgSuccess(this.txtSuccess.getText());
        data.setMsgFailure(this.txtFailure.getText());
    }

    private void getUnboundData(HastebinService data) {
        data.setPort((int)this.spinPort.getValue());
    }

    public JPanel getRootPanel() {
        return this.rootPanel;
    }

    public boolean isModified(HastebinService data) {
        if (this.isUnboundModified(data)) return true;
        if (this.txtDomain.getText() != null ? !this.txtDomain.getText().equals(data.getHost()) : data.getHost() != null)
            return true;
        if (this.chkUseSsl.isSelected() != data.getUseSSL()) return true;
        if (this.chkFileAssoc.isSelected() != data.getUseFileAssoc()) return true;
        if (this.chkLogHistory.isSelected() != data.getLogPastes()) return true;
        if (this.txtSuccess.getText() != null ? !this.txtSuccess.getText().equals(data.getMsgSuccess()) : data.getMsgSuccess() != null)
            return true;
        if (this.txtFailure.getText() != null ? !this.txtFailure.getText().equals(data.getMsgFailure()) : data.getMsgFailure() != null)
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    private boolean isUnboundModified(HastebinService data) {
        if ((int)this.spinPort.getValue() != data.getPort()) return true;
        return false;
    }

    public void setData(HastebinService data) {
        this.setUnboundData(data);
        this.txtDomain.setText(data.getHost());
        this.chkUseSsl.setSelected(data.getUseSSL());
        this.chkFileAssoc.setSelected(data.getUseFileAssoc());
        this.chkLogHistory.setSelected(data.getLogPastes());
        this.txtSuccess.setText(data.getMsgSuccess());
        this.txtFailure.setText(data.getMsgFailure());
        this.updateProtocol();
    }

    public void setUnboundData(HastebinService data) {
        this.spinPort.setValue(data.getPort());
    }

    private void updateProtocol() {
        this.lblProtocol.setText("http" + (this.chkUseSsl.isSelected() ? "s" : "") + "://");
    }

    private class CustomViewPort extends JViewport {

        public CustomViewPort(JComponent component) {
            this.setView(component);
            this.setOpaque(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking yole's answer into account, I came up with a solution that automatically saves data automatically in an "ok enough" way for light plugins.

```
new Timer(2000, new ActionListener() { // Create 2 Second Timer
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        if (isModified()) // Any Changes?
            getData(); // Save Data
    }
}).start();
```

Answer (score 0):

The IntelliJ IDEA codebase does not contain any standard databinding solution for automatically updating a persistent component when a form changes. JetBrains' own code simply copies the fields from the form to the component manually.

Comment: So in other words I either have to add the appropriate binding events for each bound component, or use a cancel/save button? Is there a way to loop through child elements recursively and call the saveData if isModified returns true?

Comment: If you're implementing a Configurable, the "Save" button is already provided to you by the framework (Configurable.apply()). In your implementation of apply(), simply call the setters for each field in your PersistentStateComponent. No need to add any events or anything fancy like that.